# GLSL strange IF behaviour

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

I am writing an iPad app running on iPad Retina using OpenGL ES 3.0

I am trying to use transform feedback for the first time and the vertex shader is acting really strangely. It seems that the boolean expression inside the IF command is always returning true for example this shader:

```
#version 300 es

in ivec2 coords;


out highp uint vertexID;

uniform sampler2D depthTexture;
uniform int yResolution;

void main () {

    ivec2 textCoords = coords;
    textCoords.y = yResolution - 1 - coords.y;

    bool val = true;
    bool val2 = false;
    if (val == val2) {
        vertexID = uint(6);
        return;
    }
    vertexID = uint(4);
    return;
}
```

When I map the VBO and check the values I get 6!

I'll post the drawing and mapping code below:

```
    glUseProgram(_ValidInputPixelsProg);

    uniforms[UNIFORM_VALID_INPUT_PIXEL_DEPTH_TEXTURE] = glGetUniformLocation(_ValidInputPixelsProg, "depthTexture");
    uniforms[UNIFORM_VALID_INPUT_PIXEL_Y_RESOLUTION] = glGetUniformLocation(_ValidInputPixelsProg, "yResolution");

    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_VALID_INPUT_PIXEL_DEPTH_TEXTURE], 10);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_VALID_INPUT_PIXEL_Y_RESOLUTION], RESOLUTION_Y);

    glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
    glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, inputTFB);
    glBindVertexArray(validPixelsVA);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _inputTFBBuffer);
    glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, RESOLUTION_INNER_XY);
    glEndTransformFeedback();
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, 0);
    glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
    glFlush();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexValidInputPixels);
    GLuint* ptr = (GLuint*)(glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, RESOLUTION_INNER_XY * sizeof(GLuint), GL_MAP_READ_BIT));
    ptr += 320 + 120;
    NSLog(@"\nshader value = %u \n", *ptr);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have the if statement check for a non-variable.

```
if (val == false)
{
    vertexID = uint(6);
    return;
}
```

Comment: if both arguments are non variables then the if behaves as expected. if at least one of the arguments is a variable then i get this strange behaviour and it will enter