# Strange GLSL if condition behavior

Tags: macos, glsl, fragment-shader

I am having a strange issue with a GLSL fragment shader on an 2020 Intel MacBook Pro with Intel Iris Plus graphics and MacOS Ventura 13. It seems that when I use an if block and don't have an else block, then the if block always executes.

I have stripped out everything else from the shader to validate it isn't something that is NaN/INFINITY, divide by zero, or something similar. I've also seen some people mention to not use == with float and even with only > or < it is still occurring. With everything stripped out the below code is what I am running:

```
#version 400
layout(location = 0)out vec4 gc_color;
void main(){
    float stackptr = -1.0;
    if(stackptr > 0.0) {
        gc_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    } // this always runs the if block
}
```

When I run this, the output is always yellow no matter what I update stackptr to. The condition seems to always evaluate to true. But also when I update it with an else block like below it seems to work correctly.

```
if(stackptr > 0.0) {
    gc_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
} else {
    gc_color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
} // this runs correctly
```

This will change the color based on what the value of stackptr is as you would expect.

I have also tried replacing "stackptr" in the condition with the value (-1.0) and that works as expected. So it seems like an issue with the variable being evaluated.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Is it possibly a driver issue? I'll try it with an Nvidia GPU soon on Windows to check.

There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897579/glsl-strange-if-behaviour) but no one has given an answer.

Comment: What value do you expect `gc_color` to take if you never assign anything to it?

Comment: When manually setting the condition without the variables (-1 < 0) I am seeing just the clear color so I would expect similar but running stackptr < 0 or anything else with the variable it always is true regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You observe undefined behaviour here. In your first shader you don't assign `gc_color` if condition is false, you can see everything. Let's consider how it can be processed by shader's compiler and GPU.

1. **Shader's compiler eliminates condition**, since `stackptr` is a constant (and it can be deduced in some cases). Result would be arbitrary, `gc_color` is never set.
2. **Dynamic branching**. Yellow color is assigned when condition is true, otherwise it's undefined (any color). Dynamic branching implies branch prediction and drop part of command's pipeline in case of miss. It can be less efficient than static branching for simple conditions.
3. **Static branching**. We calculate both branches (true and false) and choose one of them when condition is resolved. There are some preconditions for it (e.g. there should not be side-effects in branches), but your shader looks eligible for it. Some implementations execute true branch unconditionally. When condition is known and result is true, we can do a jump to a command after false block. If result is false, we allow to execute commands in false branch that **rewrite** what was set in true branch. In you case there is no false branch, so nothing is rewritten and you see yellow came from true branch.

Comment: Setting a default gc_color does appear to resolve the issue although it does seem like having to set a default color defeats the purpose of clearcolor. For clarity, this is a simplified case, the actual shader I was running was running a loop and if stackptr was > 0 its was running break; I was only doing this gc_color output to debug.

Comment: It isn't really different, loops in shaders are often unrolled for performance. We can use static branching in this case, but this time for every loop's iteration. Just do not have variable uninitialized in any cases and behaviour will be determined.